# Receiving Time Based (Every 15 minutes) Summary of failures for Google Apps Script:

Tags: google-apps-script, email-notifications

I canceled my Gsuite account a few weeks ago. I have transferred my domain to a new provider and set up a redirect for the email address that was associated with my canceled Gsuite account.

I have started Receiving Time Based (Every 15 minutes) Summary of failures for Google Apps Script:

I cannot access https://script.google.com/home/triggers? to remove the script ( I canceled the Gsuite account before I realized I had an old script running).

I have read all of the previous answers to this question however they are for developers who have still got access to https://script.google.com/home

I have contacted Google support however they are advising me to ask the question here.

Considering my circumstances am I able to delete the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*There is nothing that users from Stack Overflow can suggest you do in this case - aside contact Google Support again. This is an issue with their internal system sending out emails erroneously.*

#### More Information:

These emails are sent out automatically by the system and so aren't stoppable your end, especially if your G Suite account no longer exists. You need to contact Google Support for this, [G Suite Support](https://gsuite.google.com/support/) directly is a good bet, though without your G Suite account I do not know if you will be able to use this outlet.

The regular Google Contact page can be found [here](https://www.google.com/contact/), alternatively you can attempt to use the `Send Feedback` option available in the Gmail user interface when clicking the cog in the top right (⚙️).

#### A Temporary Fix:

In the mean time, all I can suggest you is add an email filter to deal with emails that come from `apps-scripts-notifications@google.com` - either move them directly to trash on receipt, or add them to spam. This isn't a permanent solution, I know, but it might be enough to alleviate the annoyance of all these emails until the situation gets sorted out with Google directly.

#### References:

- [G Suite Support](https://gsuite.google.com/support/)
- [Google - Contact Us](https://www.google.com/contact/)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your response - I have now set a rule to pass these to my trash directory - interestingly Google are saying there is nothing they can do to help because they do not control scripts? They are sure filling up the trash directory fast as I had a time trigger set every 15 minutes - eeek!

Comment: I'm really sorry to hear that you're having this issue, this should be something dealt with by Google. I have created an issue under the Apps Script component on Google's Issue Tracker for you [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146848395). Make sure to provide any additional information or concerns about this as a comment in the issue.